# Elastic Match Nginx Status Code with match phrase

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm looking to query elastic with messages only matching the 409 response code headers

Yet, it does match too many results : any url containing /409/ or -409- in it by example, like the match phrase operator doesn't care about leading and trailing spaces ..

```json
{
  "bool": {
    "should": [{ "match_phrase": { "message": " 409 " } }],
    "minimum_should_match": 1
  }
}
```

Thanks in advance for any comment, clue, notice, enlightenment :)

Regards

Answer (score 1):

## Tldr;

As per the documentation `match_phrase` query does not perform exact match.
It is creating a phrase from the input, and try to find match in whole text.

SO in your case returning `/409/` is expected.

You are looking for [exact match, either use a `keyword` field and search by term](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-term-query.html).

Comment: Usually tldr; is used for a short blurb accompanying a long explanation.